# Customize endnotes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, endnotes

For customizing footnotes in LaTeX, I use the `footmisc` package. Specifically, to remove indentation and text justification in footnotes, I add the following to my preamble:

```
\usepackage[hang, flushmargin, ragged]{footmisc}
```

The journal I'm submitting to now requires endotes. For that I use the `endnotes` package. But I can't find a package like `footmisc` for endnotes. What should I do to remove indentation and text justification in endnotes?

Comment: Does the journal you're submitting your paper to have its own stylistic guidelines for formatting endnotes? If so, it may not be worth your time developing a separate style for formatting endnotes because it will likely be overridden by the journal's style. You're of course free to keep sending out your papers to colleagues and interested parties, and posting your papers to your department's website, using a format/style that suits your tastes.

Comment: @Mico I'm aware that the journal will change the details of my formatting anyway, but it's nevertheless useful to know how I can customize endnotes. That said, I definitely need to suppress hyphenation and justification in the endnotes. Most journals in my field require that (to avoid any misinterpretations of hyphenations as intended word hyphens).

Comment: I know this question was asked many years ago, but still, since I got stuck in the same place, I would pretty much appreciate an answer. I saw that the question is marked as answered, but I didn't find any comment on it. is there another post answering it? tks anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can redefine `\enoteformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\footnote=\endnote

\renewcommand\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=0pt \parindent=0em
  \leavevmode\makeenmark\raggedright}

\begin{document}

text\footnote{test footnote1}
\lipsum[1]
text\footnote{test footnote2 \lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[1-7]
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]