# Customize endotes part 2

Tags: endnotes

As mentioned earlier ([Customize endnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67794/customize-endnotes)), the documentation for the [endnotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endnotes) package doesn't tell you much about how to modify and customize the appearance of endnotes. So I'm calling out to the community for some help.

I'd like my endnotes to look as follows:

1. The endnote marker should be at the left margin.
2. The endnote text should be indented throughout (i.e. not just the first line of each endnote).
3. One line of space (i.e. `\baselineskip`) between each note.
4. No text justification (i.e. `\raggedright`).
5. I'd like to be able to set the size of the endnote text (e.g. `\normalsize`).

I get from [Gonzalo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67797/9077) that I can redefine `\enoteformat` to accomplish some or all (?) of these things, but playing with this hasn't gotten me anywhere close `:(`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes,lipsum}
    %\renewcommand\enoteformat{} % perhaps doing something here would do the trick?
\begin{document}
\endnote{\lipsum[1]}\endnote{\lipsum[2]}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a MWE to play with?

Comment: @egreg I deliberately didn't include a MWE because it wouldn't contain anything useful. But I'll add one in a moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard definition of `\enoteformat` is

```
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip\z@ \leftskip\z@ \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
```

Taking this as a model, here's what you may want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\enotesize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{%
  \raggedright
  \leftskip=1.8em
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\theenmark. \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\baselineskip}}%
}

\begin{document}
\endnote{\lipsum[1]}\endnote{\lipsum[2]}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same, but perhaps better and surely easier, with the `enotez` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{sverre}{paragraph}
 {
  heading=\section*{#1},
  notes-sep=\baselineskip,
  format=\normalsize\normalfont\raggedright\leftskip1.8em,
  number=\makebox[0pt][r]{#1.\ }\ignorespaces,
 }

\begin{document}
\endnote{\lipsum[1]}\endnote{\lipsum[2]}

\printendnotes[sverre]
\end{document}
```

If you want the indentation to be as wide as the parindent and the numbers at the left margin, then do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{sverre}{paragraph}
 {
  heading=\section*{#1},
  notes-sep=\baselineskip,
  format=\normalsize\normalfont\raggedright\leftskip\normalparindent,
  number=\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\normalparindent][l]{#1.}}\ignorespaces,
 }

\begin{document}
Something\endnote{\lipsum[1]} to show the parindent\endnote{\lipsum[2]}

\printendnotes[sverre]
\end{document}
```

I added `showframe` just to make sure the specifications are respected

[image]

***Notes***
The parameter `\leftskip` is the distance from the global left margin to the actual left margin of the text. The `\raggedright` command sets it to zero, so we override this later, and sets `\rightskip` to a stretchable space; it also sets `\parindent` to zero, so I defined `\normalparindent` to remember its value. You may want to try also `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package that allows for (rare) hyphenation in order to reduce the raggedness. With the double makebox trick we set a zero width box with its contents sticking to its left, containing a box `\normalparindent` wide, with the contents shoved to the left.

Comment: I followed the ``enotez`` suggestion. The endnote mark is not at the left margin, though. When it says ``\leftskip1.8em``, what is this ``1.8em`` from? Also, is there a way to set the distance from the margin to the endnote text? I would like this to be the same as ``\parindent``.

Comment: @Sverre The `format` is stored and executed at each paragraph, so I assume `em` refers to the current font. If you want the number at the left margin, then say `number=\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1.8em][l]{#1.}}`, but the alignment when you step to two digit numbers will be funny. If you want `\parindent`, it's slightly more complicated; I'll add it.

Comment: What I meant was this: ``\leftskip`` sets the distance from something to something else. What are these somethings? From playing around with it, it seems as if it sets the distance from the margin to the endnote text? Meaning there is another command that sets the distance from the margin to the endnote mark?

Comment: Actually, with ``number=\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1.8em][l]{#1.}}``, the endnote marker bleeds into the margin.

Comment: @Sverre Yes, an `\ignorespaces` was missing, because the package implicitly adds a space between the number and the text. I guess that a key for setting this might qualify for a feature request to the package maintainer.

Comment: Great, this works. The finer details escape me, nevertheless ``:)``.

Comment: @Sverre I added some notes. You're better not to have `enumerate` or `itemize` in your endnotes. If you do, something different has to be set up.

Comment: No one should have enumerated or itemized lists in their footnotes or endnotes ``:)``

Comment: Long ago but helpful for me in using endnote package.  But I would like parbox instead of makebox for having multiple paragraphs in an endnote.  I tried enotez package but it gives errors kernel command endnote already defined.

Comment: @RobRutten The `\makebox` is just to print the note number. Please, open a new question with the details.

Comment: @egreg  You are fast!  But night sleep reminded me that  multi-paragraph per command \def needs \long before.  I had a \myendnote redefinition forgetting that.   Solved.  Your \makebox does its job (as many other hints from you in this forum, I now thank Stackexchange in publications).

Comment: @egreg I find that with \long I may also have itemize lists in endnotes.